# Modular Exponentiation

Tags: python, mathematics

I want to solve the following for \$x\$ (in Python):

\$x^{101} = 8765 \ (\mod{9691573})\$

I coded this:

```
n = 8765
power = 101
mod = 9691573

x = 0
while x < mod:
    if (x ** power) % mod == n:
        break
    x += 1

print x
```

This is basically the "brute force" approach.

What is the most efficient way to solve this problem programmatically?

**Note:**

> solving the equation \$x^n = a \mod{M}\$ for the unknown \$x\$ in modular arithmetic means to find an integer \$x\$ such that \$x^n - a\$ is a multiple of the modulus \$M\$

Comment: This is the RSA problem with e=101 and n=9691573. Factor the modulus `n`, compute `phi(n)`. Compute `d` such that `e * d = 1 mod phi(n)` using [extended euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). Compute `8765^d mod n` using [square-and multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Read the wikipedia article on [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) for details.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'd say this qualifies as an answer instead if a comment.

Comment: @CodesInChaos note that the modulus is prime.

Comment: Is this really a code review question? It technically contains a working piece of code, but to efficiently compute this you will need to write completely different code. I think this would be a better fit of stackoverflow.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I disagree whole heartedly. This is a great fit for Code Review. (8 other people seem to agree with me about that.) We often deal with [tag:performance] issues. Suggesting alternative algorithms is commonplace here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: this is not exactly the RSA problem. For it to be the RSA problem, the modulus would have to be composite. Turns out, in this case, the modulus is prime.

Note also: this is not the discrete log problem, as in the discrete log problem we are trying to find the exponent, not the base.

That said, you can find the answer using the method that CodesInChaos recommended.

1. Factor `mod`, easy, `mod` is already prime, so it is factored.
2. Compute `phi(mod)`. This is the euler totient function. For primes, `phi(mod)=mod-1`. So in your case, `phi(mod)=9691572`.
3. Compute `d` such that `power*d=1 modulo phi(mod)`. Use the extended euclidean algorithm to do this. You will get `d=7868405`. There are python libraries that will do it for you (pycrypto [Crypto.Util.number.inverse](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Util.number-module.html#inverse))
4. Compute `8765^d modulo mod`. In python you want to do this using `pow`. `pow` takes a third argument (a modulus) which is way optimized when compared to `**` followed by `%`. It does the square-and-multiply method. In this case, `pow(8765, 7868405, 9691573)` returns `680457`.

You can check the answer by doing `pow(680457, 101, 9691573)` and make sure it return `8765`.

If the modulus were not prime, you'd have to factor it to compute phi(mod). After that, everything else is the same.